Job posting still open, Want to be considered again but couldn't complete Interview process before due to family Illness
I applied to a job opening about 6 months ago and was contacted about a month ago for the first stage of interviews conducted by phone.
That went well, they were very interested in my candidacy and the hiring manager and team and myself proceeded to schedule the next stage of interviews, again by phone.
Unfortunately, at that time, I could not go forward in the next stage of the interview process to due a family illness and subsequent death which I communicated to the hiring manager by email and that is where it was left.
The job is still open and available one month later and I am interested in being considered for it again and my family situation has been resolved.
How can I re-engage and say I am still interested in the job opportunity and participate again in the interview process ?  Should I contact the hiring manager directly ?  HR ?  What should I say when I contact them ?
Any advice or tips would be helpful !

Write an email to the manager?  This does not seem complicated.

Just be honest that you had a personal situation that keep you from participating previously. You don't have to be detailed.
Focus on your skillset and experience. After all they need the candidate.
Don't overthink it.

Just send an email to the hiring manager (maybe even as a reply to the first one you sent) saying that you've finished dealing with the situation, saw that the job posting was still up, and would like to re-submit your candidacy, if they're still interested in interviewing you.


I could not go forward in the next stage of the interview process to due a family illness and subsequent death which I communicated to the hiring manager by email and that is where it was left.
... my family situation has [now] been resolved.

If you were already explicit with the hiring manager at the time, that you were having to cope with a dying close family member and a funeral, then that would be considered a very good reason not to be able to proceed to interviews for a while.
Unlike the advice of the top answer, I don't think it would pay to be non-specific here about a "personal situation".
I would just be direct again, recapping that you were offered an interview several weeks ago, but had to decline whilst dealing with a sudden illness in the family and funeral arrangements.
Just don't lay it on thick or solicit sympathy - you want to explain your good reason, but don't want to be seen as still reeling from the loss, or using the circumstances to beg for the job.
The question you want to ask is a simple one: now that you are returning to interviewing, and seeing that the same position remains open, is there still an opportunity for you to arrange an interview?
